# AS3_Manual and Auto button event handler troubleshoot

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a project that has 30-40 frames with movieclips in each frame.  Think of each frame as a slide.  There are buttons at the bottom of the stage that control the functionality of these slides (eg play, pause, next, prev, speed up, slow down, and refresh).  However, the two buttons that are giving me headaches are a manual mode and auto mode buttons.  Their names are exactly how they sound, manual should stop after each mc plays in each frame.  Auto should play each frame in sequence.  The way I have it set up now is each mc fires an EventDispatch of "finished" and "stopped".  Depending on which button was clicked last, the stage will listen for the event and either pause for 4 seconds (setInterval) and gotoNextFrame, or stop on that frame until the user clicks next.  I tried a switch case, but it would not allow for eventlisteners within each case Error # 1009.  Here is the code I have for the buttons so far...

I am fairly novice so be gentle.  And I will upload flv if it will help any more.  Thank you very very very much.

```
//Manual button actions
function manual_onClick(event:MouseEvent)
{
    manual_btn.visible = false;
    auto_btn.visible = true;
    gotoAndStop(currentFrame);
    stage.removeEventListener("finished", mcFinished);
    stage.addEventListener("stopped",stopmc,false,0);


    function stopmc(e:Event):void
    {
        trace("mc stop");
        stage.removeEventListener("stopped",stopmc);
    }
}


//Auto button actions
function auto_onClick(event:MouseEvent)
{
    gotoAndStop(currentFrame + 1);
    manual_btn.visible = true;
    auto_btn.visible = false;
    stage.addEventListener("finished", mcFinished2,false,1);


    function mcFinished2(e:Event):void
    {
        var ID2 = setInterval(goNextFrame2,3000);
        trace("mc complete");
        function goNextFrame2()
        {
            gotoAndStop( currentFrame + 1 );
            clearInterval( ID2 );
            stage.removeEventListener("finished", mcFinished2);
        }
    }
}
```

and the dispatchEvent from each mc

```
stop();

dispatchEvent(new Event("finished", true));
dispatchEvent(new Event("stopped", true));
```

Thanks again!
Scott

Here is the switch case attempt...

```
function onBtnClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var theBtn:DisplayObject = evt.currentTarget as DisplayObject;
    var lastBtn:DisplayObject;


    if (lastBtn)
    {
        lastBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnClicked);
    }

    lastBtn = theBtn;

    switch (theBtn)
    {
        case auto_btn :
            //button one actions;
            gotoAndStop(currentFrame + 1);
            manual_btn.visible = true;
            auto_btn.visible = false;
            trace("auto button clicked");

            stage.addEventListener("finished", mcFinished);
            function mcFinished(e:Event):void
            {
                var ID = new setInterval(goNextFrame,3000);
                trace("mc complete");
                function goNextFrame()
                {
                    gotoAndStop( currentFrame + 1 );
                    clearInterval( ID );
                    stage.removeEventListener("finished", mcFinished);
                    stage.addEventListener("finished", mcFinished);
                }
            }


            break;
        case manual_btn :

            manual_btn.visible = false;
            auto_btn.visible = true;
            trace("manual button clicked");

            stage.removeEventListener("finished", mcFinished);
            stage.addEventListener("stopped",stopmc,false,1);


            function stopmc(e:Event):void
            {
                trace("mc stop");
                stage.addEventListener("stopped",stopmc);
                stage.removeEventListener("stopped",stopmc);
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working for you?   You mention a switch statement but I don't see one in your code.

Comment: The code above only works for 1 cycle.  Meaning, I can only click the manual button, and auto button once before the code starts listening for both dispatchevents even though each button should remove the previous.  The switch case is posted above.  It receives this error, but will still publish.  TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter listener must be non-null.
 at flash.events::EventDispatcher/addEventListener()
 at flash.display::Stage/addEventListener()

Comment: where does the code above live?  on the first frame of the timeline that hold all your slide frames?

Comment: The code for all the buttons are on the first frame.  All the slides are in the following frames 2-35 of the main timeline.  The dispatch events are placed within mc's on frames 2-35.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some recommendations.

First,  you don't need two separate events ("finished/stopped") at the end of each of your clips, as they are serving the exact same function.  I'd suggest just doing one event and using a built in event like `Event.COMPLETE`.   so the last frame of your individual clips would look like this:

```
stop();
dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE, true));
```

On the first frame of your individual clips, I would add this:

```
//use these two listeners so that the clip is only listening when it's being displayed on the timeline.
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init,false,0,true);
this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,unload,false,0,true);

function init(e:Event){
    stage.addEventListener("Play",playMe,false,0,true);
    stage.addEventListener("Pause",pauseMe,false,0,true);
}

function unload(e:Event){
    stage.removeEventListener("Play",playMe,false);
    stage.removeEventListener("Pause",pauseMe,false);
}

function playMe(e:Event){
    play();
}

function pauseMe(e:Event){
    stop();
}
```

Here is how I would do the rest of your code:

```
stop();  //stop the main timeline

manual_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnClicked);
auto_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBtnClicked);

var nextTimer:Timer = new Timer(4000,1); //a timer to wait 4 seconds before auto next.
nextTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, nextSlide); //what the timer should do when it's done

var isAuto:Boolean = true;  //a variable that holds the state of automatically continuing to the next slide. set it's default to either true or false

this.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,slideComplete); //listens for any slide complete event

//this function will get run whenever one of your slides is complete.
function slideComplete(e:Event = null):void {
    if(isAuto){
       nextTimer.reset();
       nextTimer.start(); //start the timer
    }
}

function onBtnClicked(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    manual_btn.visible = (evt.currentTarget == manual_btn);
    auto_btn.visible = (evt.currentTarget == auto_btn);

    isAuto = auto_btn.visible;
}

function nextSlide(e:Event = null):void {  //default e to null so you can call this function directly nextSlide(); - have your next button click call this function too
    nextTimer.reset(); //stop/reset the timer 
    nextFrame(); //tell the main timeline to go to the next frame
}

function prevSlide(e:Event = null):void {
    nextTimer.reset(); //reset the timer in case it's running
    prevFrame();
}

function pause(e:Event = null):void {
    nextTimer.reset():
    stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("Pause")); //have your individual clips listen for this event and stop
}

function playSlide(e:Event = null):void {
    nextTimer.reset();
    stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("Play")); //have your individual clips listen for this event and play;
}
```

The reason you want to reset the timer on all the button clicks is in case you hit previous or next in that 4 second window when the auto next is waiting to fire.  example:  auto next is turned on,  1 second after the slide finished, you hit the previous button - it moves to the previous slide,  3 seconds later the timer the would fire and it would move to the next frame.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I do have a couple of comments though.  First, I like your approach better, but I forgot to mention that my main goal is to keep as much of the code on the first frame.  Reason being is that this will be a template for other animations that I have to revise.  I posted the .fla with the old switchcase that can be downloaded at[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/cz9a9v398dta94g/Example_Sizings_GE_0_backup_19.fla.  some of the movieclips are pretty jank also because they were done a long time ago.  If you get a chance take a look.

Comment: Also, I could not get the auto, manual, or play buttons to work with your code.  The swf does play with a 4 sec delay with each frame, but I want to be able to switch modes between auto (which plays each slide with a delay) and manual which will only allow for slides to be viewed with the prev/next and numbered buttons at the bottom of the screen.  You will see what I am talking about if you download.  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: fyi the numbered buttons at the bottom do not work because I have not finished the array yet.  still a slow neub

Comment: and for the sake of confidentiality I had to remove frames 10-30, but here is the jist of the overall idea at this [link] https://www.dropbox.com/s/t00s81x77843fi8/Example_Sizings_GE_0_backup_20.fla

Comment: It's not working because you're not dispatching a complete event at the end of each slide.  either change you slides to dispatch Event.COMPLETE, or change listener on the first frame to listen for `"finished"` instead of `Event.COMPLETE`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had to modify your code a bit, but it works perfectly.  And I learned about Event.COMPLETE in the process.  Thank you for you time and efforts.  Have a merry xmas

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem,  and if you had to change anything that alters the message of answer, please post it either as a comment or in your question for future visitors